# What is the "coverage condition"?

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

[The source for the `State` transformer in mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Class.html) states:

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Instances for other mtl transformers
--
-- All of these instances need UndecidableInstances,
-- because they do not satisfy the coverage condition.
```

What is the "coverage condition"? All I can tell is that it has something to do with MTPCs and fundeps.

Comment: See http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Section 7.6.3.2 of [the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) tells us what the coverage condition is:

> The Coverage Condition. For each functional dependency, `tvsleft -> tvsright`, of the class, every type variable in `S(tvsright)` must appear in `S(tvsleft)`, where `S` is the substitution mapping each type variable in the class declaration to the corresponding type in the instance declaration.

In plain English, this means that if you have a type class with fundeps, for example:

```
class Convert a b | a -> b where
  convert :: a -> b
```

you can define the following instances:

```
instance Convert String String   -- no type variables
instance Convert [a]    [a]      -- type var a present on both sides
instance Convert (a,b)  a        -- a on the right => a on the left
```

but *not* the following instances:

```
instance Convert String a        -- a only present on the right
instance Convert a      (a,b)    -- b only present on the right
```

Answer (score 3):

It is defined in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/fd-chr/jfp06.pdf) by Simon Peyton-Jones. Definition 7 defines `Coverage Condition`. I would quote the exact definition but alas, I don't know how to reproduce the mathematical symbols here.